# Ra in the Torah

Tags: egypt

Shavua Tov. In Exodus 10:10, it says......וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֲלֵהֶ֗ם יְהִ֨י כֵ֤ן יְהֹוָה֙ עִמָּכֶ֔ם כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֛ר אֲשַׁלַּ֥ח אֶתְכֶ֖ם וְאֶת־טַפְּכֶ֑ם רְא֕וּ כִּ֥י רָעָ֖ה נֶ֥גֶד פְּנֵיכֶֽם:

Now, רָעָ֖ה is translated by Rashi as being a star by that name.

Has anyone ever come across an opinion in any other commentary that says that Pharaoh was actually referring to the well known Egyptian Sun deity who name is also רָעָ֖ה ?

( My question needs a little Egyptology 101 to understand )

The answer will also help me come closer to figuring out the Pharaoh of the Exodus, since not all Pharaohs were "Ra worshippers".

Comment: If רעמסס is also related to Ra then the ayin here could make some sense.

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed, Ra in Egyptian has an ayin.

Comment: Ramses means "Ra is the one who bore him" in Egyptian.

Comment: I did some research on this once but unfortunately I can't find my old computer at the moment. Though I don't recall finding particularly old sources discussing this, other than Rashi.

Comment: Reb Aryeh Kaplan translates Poti Pher Ra as the Priest of the House of Ra.

Answer (score 2):

Umberto Cassuto writes in his perush on Shmos: ראו כי רעה נגד פניכם; שימו לב לכך, שאם תפצירו בי הפצרה נוספת, צפויה לכם רעה. גם כאן אולי, כפי מה שהוצע כבר, יש לראות מעין רמז לאל המצרי רע, אל השמש, ראש הפנתיאון המצרי: דעו כי כוח האל שלי יקום נגדכם (במדרש חז“ל: כוכב יש ששמו רעה). Samuel Rosenblatt of JTS took up the same argument in *Journal of Biblical Literature*
Vol. 60.

Note also that Yalqut Shimoni says לפי שראה פרעה באצטנגינות ואמר להם לישראל ראו כי רעה נגד פניכם אמר להם אני רואה באצטגנינות שלי כוכב אחד עולה לקראתכם שמו רעה והוא סימן דם . . . (also Shir Hashirim Rabba in some versions) but Lekah Tov says ראו כי רעה נגד פניכם. זה בעל צפון, אמר להם נגד דרכיכם טעותו עומד והוא יריע לכם.

In a similar example, it is well known that both some rishonim and some modern scholars assume וַיִּקַּח אֶת־עֲטֶרֶת־מַלְכָּם in II Sam. 12:30 refers to מִלְכֹּם שִׁקֻּץ עַמֹּנִים (I Kings 11:5 and elsewhere), including Rashi: את עטרת מלכם תועבת בני עמון מלכם שמו לשון מולך.

IMO it's easy to imagine that this was originally a tradition based on the identification of רעה with Ra but, because none of the medieval scribes were actually familiar with Egyptian cosmogony, it became confused.